# Are hadoop committers used in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

My team is using Spark Structured Streaming to sink messages from kafka to HDFS. We're in the late stages of migrating this component to instead sink messages to AWS S3, and in connection with that we hit upon a couple of issues regarding hadoop committers.

I've come to understand that the default "file" committer (documented [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#Switching_to_an_S3A_Committer)) is unsafe to use in S3, which is why [this page in the spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/cloud-integration.html) recommends using the "directory" (i.e. staging) committer, and in later versions of hadoop they also recommend to use the "magic" committer.

However, it's not clear whether spark structured streaming even use committers. There's no "_SUCCESS" file in the destination (as compared to normal spark jobs), and the documentation regarding committers used in streaming is non-existent.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Afraid not. they don't so much commit work as checkpoint it, and nobody has (yet) to do an s3-friendly checkpointer (as of march 2022). the placeholders for that in the s3a committer are in hadoop-3.3.1 (you can commit/abort the writing of a file), but someone has to do the coding and testing for it. this could be your opportunity to get involved in the code.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. So essentially, I read that as spark structured streaming is unreliable/unsafe to use on aws S3. How do you know this by the way? I haven't found any documentation related to this topic.

Comment: don't know about that. because s3 is now consistent, things may be better. but polling for changes in s3 to look for new files is still slow and expensive, and probably going to miss files whose upload began before the previous window, as their timestamps is time of upload initiation, not completion

Comment: Have a look at [SPARK-40039](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-40039), to be delivered in 3.4.0.